# Filter a table with a particular attribute using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here i am trying to filter(exact match) my table based on the selection of the dropdown. In a way i am able to do that but for few records it is filtering down some other records as well.

I want to filter two tables with (column name- Input File ID) the exact match of input that is given to the filter not with other columns of the tables.

If i filter it with {inputFileID: '7', name: 'Expense'} the result is

[image]

I want it to be

[image]

what am i doing wrong, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Pluker : https://plnkr.co/edit/xIQ0DWNzImrJijvXabE6?p=preview

```
$scope.selectedInputFile = function (search) {
        var copyOfInputData = angular.copy(search);
        $scope.itemList = copyOfInputData;
       $scope.inputRoleFilter = $scope.itemList.inputFileID
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter: should get an object containing attributes and values. So `$scope.inputRoleFilter` should become `{inputFileID: $scope.itemList.inputFileID}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/d0aRz29Dv4nnX3Pijhwn?p=preview) - `filter` should be transformed to `{inputFileId : search.inputFileID}` with specifying `: true`, because you want *"exact match"*:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in inputFileRole | filter: {'inputFileId':search.inputFileID} : true"></tr>
```